# circle and text to rotate separately

Tags: javascript, html, css, backbone.js, backbone-views

can you tell me how to make the border of the circle alone to rotate... instead of making the entire circle with text in to rotate....
tried to debug but could not find it out...
providing my code below

```
<script type="x-template" id="underscore-template">
  <div class="box" id="box-<%= number %>" style="top: <%= top %>px; left: <%= left %>px; background: rgb(0,0,<%= color %>);">
    Count : <%= content %>       
  </div>
</script>
```

Comment: You'll have to have an inner container that rotates the exact same amount in the opposite direction

Comment: @ZachSaucier: can you update in fiddle its confusing pls

Comment: Meaning if the parent is rotated `30 degrees` then you have an inner element that rotates `-30 degrees`

Comment: @ZachSaucier: can you pls update in fiddle

Answer (score 0):

You were close. [Here's a Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/n2P6P/)

```
<script type="x-template" id="template">
    <div class="display">
        <div class="box" id="box-<%= number %>" style="top: <%= top %>px; left: <%= left %>px; transform: rotate(<%= degrees %>deg);-webkit-transform:rotate(<%= degrees %>deg);">
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            Count : <%= degrees %>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Mys solution for you use 2 nested div, in which the one representing the circle needs to be inside the one with the sphere
e.g:

```
<div class='sphere with count or whatevs'> <div class='rotating circle'></div></div>
```

Comment: This did not provide anything in addition to the comments above and is not a full solution